# File Api Cordova/phonegap

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic

Preciso de ajuda, não consigo fazer funcionar a File api, os comandos executam todos com sucesso, mas quando entro no meu gerenciador de arquivos do celular eu não encontro o arquivo criado
estou usando o ng-cordova agora, mas ja testei de umass 10 formas diferentes, 
Este é o meu fonte agora.

```
 aux = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
        console.log(aux);
        $cordovaFile.createFile(aux, "file.txt", true).then(function (success) {
            console.log("createFile success");
            console.log(success);


            $cordovaFile.checkFile(aux, "file.txt").then(function (success) {
                console.log("checkFile success");
                console.log(success);

                $cordovaFile.readAsText(aux, "file.txt").then(function (success) {
                    console.log("readAsText success");
                    console.log(success);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("readAsText error");
                    console.log(error);
                });

                $cordovaFile.writeFile(aux, "file.txt", "teste", true).then(function (success) {
                    console.log("writeFile success");
                    console.log(success);

                    $cordovaFile.readAsText(aux, "file.txt").then(function (success) {
                        console.log("readAsText success");
                        console.log(success);
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log("readAsText error");
                        console.log(error);
                    });

                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("writeFile error");
                    console.log(error);
                });



            }, function (error) {
                console.log("checkFile error");
                console.log(error);
            });
```

obs: ja tentei compilando o projeto e via phonegap developer